# Excel Macro Button

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to create a button in Excel to trigger a Macro. So say I have a button that says "Start" that I can click to start a Macro instead of using a hotkey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into the VBA IDE (by clicking to edit your macro or similar).  On the left hand side, right click your project, do `Insert`,`User Form`.  Drag a `command button` over from the tools, double click it to generate an event handler.

Fill in the code and run the macro to display the form.

Answer (score 7):

If you use the 'Forms' toolbar, you will be able to draw a button and assign a macro to it. See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291073) for details.

Comment: Sometimes I use the controls as shown in the document, but when things get complex, the controls have problems. I use more and more the technique described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619558/using-radio-buttons-in-an-excel-macro/17620806#17620806)