# Alternatives to Illegible Drop Down Lists? Excel 2016

Tags: excel

Just putting this out there to find out if anyone has a solution to this yet.
When presenting my workbook on a projector, it is near impossible to read the drop down list. And the nifty combo box workaround is gone in excel 2016.

Anyone have any alternatives that are working for them?

Comment: This is more a super user question I suspect. They will want to know what do you mean by" the nifty combobox workaround has gone" ? Comboboxes are still around in Excel 2016. Also, is it that the wording is too small or out of focus or both?

Comment: @QHarr Apparently in Office 2013 and prior, you had the option to change font sizes in the combo boxes. That feature was removed in 2016. So now when you using a combo box to try and get around the data validation drop downs being too small to read, you have the same problem.

Comment: What office subscription are you using? And is this Mac or Windows?

Comment: @QHarr Office 365 and Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my edition of Office (MS Professional Plus 2016, Windows) I can do:

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddComboFont()

    Dim cb As ComboBox

    With ActiveSheet

        Set cb = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", Link:=False, _
                                 DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=322.5, Top:=11.5, Width:=176.5, Height:= _
                                 61.5).Object

        cb.Font.Size = 20

    End With

End Sub
```

Same thing can be achieved with right-click on combobox > properties > Font

This applies to `ActiveX` comboboxes. You can't change the Font size on the `Form control` combobox. This can be a trade off as Form control can be better behaved than ActiveX particularly when users have different screen resolutions. See my answer here [Excel Comboboxes double up on some PCs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875676/excel-comboboxes-double-up-on-some-pcs/47454821#47454821)

Comment: I'm telling you that I can't do that on mine. For many other people, they can't do it either. How does your version have an option for font in the properties?

Comment: This is what I am trying to ascertain. Can you set the font with code? By referencing your combobox and then doing .Font.Size?

Comment: I just tried using the code above and that also did nothing as well.  Is there a way to add code to the combo box to change font?

Comment: Did you put it in a standard code module and run with a sheet selected? It should have added a combobox to that sheet or given you an error. Did nothing really happen?

Comment: Got it running now. So this is an active x combo box correct? I still have to code in range and all that stuff? There is no control option when I look at properties is what I'm getting at.

Comment: You can’t change the font on a form control combo but should be able to on an ActiveX. You should be able to manually add an activex combobox and right click properties > font > set the font size you want

Comment: you have helped greatly. Are there any caveats to this? My coworkers can use this with not problems like any other dropdown?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167944/discussion-between-qharr-and-remi).

Comment: I have added some info in chat

Comment: I have a summary of the differences between the 2 types of controls (for example, a ***form control* combo box** and an ***ActiveX control* combo box**) as an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49263001/8112776).