# Excel ActiveX controls changing size with resolution still not fixed?

Tags: vba, excel, activex, excel-2013

OK, this might be a bit of a generic and repeated `non-code` question but the latest article I can find about this is from over 2 years ago, so I'm wondering if there's been a fix or an update or maybe some clever dude out there has cracked the secret to curing this.

Every time I extend my screen while Excel (2007, 2010 or 2013) is running, and every time I unplug from an extension while Excel is running, my ActiveX controls are rendered useless, because with each click they either shrink or get bigger, depending on if I extended or unplugged.

This happens until I close the Excel application and restart it, unfortunately if I've saved it while the buttons are bigger/smaller they might end up stuck like that.

There is a thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385803/how-to-stop-activex-objects-automatically-changing-size-in-office) which has a bit code to help deal with the issue but quite frankly I'm hoping by now, two years later, someone has a slightly more efficient method of dealing with it.

I've took to using hyperlinks to run macros now but that's no good for my drop-boxes and things. And for me personally, I can just make sure I close Excel before extending/unplugging, but the real issue is I'm developing apps for people around the company and it's starting to cause problems with these damned buttons.

Does anyone know of a definitive fix for this yet?

Comment: No, however...try using MS-Access? If your developing 'apps' then it's much better for it than excel, and it's more or less the same VBA.

Comment: I can't because most people don't have Access to Access at work. Or rather, they may actually be able to download it... It could be an option. I was thinking about using VB.NET to have a control hub that manipulates Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need ActiveX buttons to run macros, use Shapes instead. You can assign macros to a s shape's Click event. Right-click the shape and select "Assign Macro".